# How to center header and numbers in a scientific table and hyphen between numbers

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, hyphenation, threeparttable

I just started to use LaTex and it's an amazing tool. Exposing my limited knowledge on code development, could someone please provide a solution to my problem? I need a hyphen between the age intervals. It is important that age and VO2 be centered under men and female. Additionally, I need all the numbers to be centered under age and VO2 and the numbers in the last column not to merge. Could someone with extended knowledge on LaTex-coding please show me how this is done? The code is presented under the text. Thanks in advance

Regards Svein

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\renewcommand\thetable{2}
\caption{Cadirorespiratory fitness stratified by age}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=1.3] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.3] % Column 3
    S[table-format=1.6] % Column 4
    S[table-format=1.5] % Column 5
}

\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Male} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 &  
{Age}  & {\splitcell{VO2{\footnotesize \(^b\)(\(mL/kg/min\)})\\}} &   
{Age} & {\splitcell{VO2{\footnotesize \(^b\)(\(mL/kg/min\)})}}\\
\midrule
& 20 29 & 46.1 & 20 29 & 38.2\\

& \numrange{30}{39} & 38.5 & \numrange{30}{39} & 43\\

& \numrange{40}{49}  & 26.7 & \numrange{40}{49} & 21.6\\

& \numrange{50}{59}  & 29.1 & \numrange{50}{59}  & 30.6\\

& \geq 60 & 28.3 & \geq 60 & 27.3\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If by "between numbers" you mean a range, that should be an endash, entered by `--` (two adjacent hyphens).

Answer (score 3):

- first column is empty, remove it
- in answer is consider `siunitx` version 3
- columns with range numbers are selected as `c` type

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%\usepackage{babel}                % which one?
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,
            threeparttable}       % <---
%\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <--- delete % if you like to have thicker rule
%\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <--- delete % if you like to have thicker 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
\usepackage{siunitx} % considered v3
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.1,
         range-phrase= {\,--\,}
         }
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Cadirorespiratory fitness stratified by age}
\begin{tabular}{
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 2
    c                   % Column 3
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 4
                }
    \toprule
\mcc[2]{Male}
            &   \mcc[2]{Female}                     \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
Age     &   {\makecell{VO2\tnote{b}\\  
                      (\unit{mL/kg/min})}}
            &   Age   
                &   {\makecell{VO2\tnote{b}\\
                              (\unit{mL/kg/min})}}  \\
    \midrule
\numrange{20}{29}    
        & 46.1  & \numrange{20}{29} & 38.2          \\
\numrange{30}{39} 
        & 51.5  & \numrange{30}{39} & 33            \\
\numrange{40}{49}  
        & 35.7  & \numrange{40}{49} & 31.6          \\
\numrange{50}{59}  
        & 39.1  & \numrange{50}{59} & 29.6          \\
$\geq$ 60   & 30.3  & $\geq 60$     & 27.3          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[b]    some description
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I need Male and Female to be placed above Age and VO2 as it is in the draft. Could you please provide a  suggestion om how to do that without misalignment?

Comment: @Svein, ups, I interchange order of table rows. Corrected now. What is misaligned? See if answer now better fulfil your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, with some modifications. In particular, I used the `\makecell` command, from the homonymous package, which is designed to allow line breaks in standard cells. As to the endash for numerical ranges, it is an option set with `siunitx` by the key `range-phrase=`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable} % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt} % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt} % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2} % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\sisetup{range-phrase= --}
\centering
\renewcommand\thetable{2}
\caption{Cardiorespiratory fitness stratified by age}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{
    c % Column 1
    S[table-format=1.3] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.3] % Column 3
    S[table-format=1.6] % Column 4
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 5
}

\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Men}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 &
{Age} & {\makecell{VO2\(^b\)\\ (\unit{mL/kg/min})\\}}
 &
{Age} & {\makecell{VO2\(^b\)\\(\unit{mL/kg/min})}}\\
\midrule
& \numrange{20}{29} & 46.1 & \numrange{20}{29} & 38.2\\

& \numrange{30}{39} & 51.5 & \numrange{30}{39} & 33\\

& \numrange{40}{49} & 35.7 & \numrange{40}{49} & 31.6\\

& \numrange{50}{59} & 39.1 & \numrange{50}{59} & 29.6\\

& {60--\phantom{90}} & 30.3 & {60--\phantom{90}} & 27.3\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: a modification of the code to have ‘Men’ and ‘Female’ better centred w.r.t. ‘Age’ and ‘VO2’:

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\sisetup{range-phrase= --}
\centering
\renewcommand\thetable{2}
\caption{Cardiorespiratory fitness stratified by age}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{
    c % Column 1
    S[table-format=1.3] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.3] % Column 3
    S[table-format=1.6] % Column 4
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 5
}

\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Men\hskip1.5em\mbox{}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female\hskip1.5em\mbox{}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 &
{Age} & {\makecell{VO2\(^b\)\\ \footnotesize(\unit{mL/kg/min})\\}}
 &
{Age} & {\makecell{VO2\(^b\)\\ \footnotesize(\unit{mL/kg/min})}}\\
\midrule
& \numrange{20}{29} & 46.1 & \numrange{20}{29} & 38.2\\

& \numrange{30}{39} & 51.5 & \numrange{30}{39} & 33\\

& \numrange{40}{49} & 35.7 & \numrange{40}{49} & 31.6\\

& \numrange{50}{59} & 39.1 & \numrange{50}{59} & 29.6\\

& {60--\phantom{90}} & 30.3 & {60--\phantom{90}} & 27.3\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. Could you please demonstrate how to place Male and Female above and in the middle of Age and VO2. At the moment, Male and Female are placed a bit too much to the right. Furthermore, could you show me how to perfectly align the line under Male with the other lines on that side? I need the lines to match.

Comment: @Svein: I have a solution (by trial and error) for the placement of Men and Female, but what do you mean with the ‘perfect alignment’ of the lines below these heads with the other lines?

Answer (score 2):

The table, as is, commits a few sins: never repeat data!

I present here two realizations, with a few adjustments for the first one which is like yours.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}

\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
\DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
\captionsetup[table]{position=top}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setcounter{table}{1}% just for the example, isn't it?

\caption{Cardiorespiratory fitness stratified by age}

\begin{tabular}{
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 2
    c                   % Column 3
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 4
}

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Male} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
Age & {\splitcell{VO2\textsuperscript{\itshape b} \\ (\si{mL/kg/min})}} &   
Age & {\splitcell{VO2\textsuperscript{\itshape b} \\ (\si{mL/kg/min})}} \\
\midrule
20--29    & 46.1 & 20--29    & 38.2 \\
30--39    & 38.5 & 30--39    & 43   \\
40--49    & 26.7 & 40--49    & 21.6 \\
50--59    & 29.1 & 50--59    & 30.6 \\
$\geq 60$ & 28.3 & $\geq 60$ & 27.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\caption{Isn't this better?}

\begin{tabular}{
    @{}
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 3
    @{}
}

\toprule
Age & \multicolumn{2}{c}{VO2\textsuperscript{\itshape b} (\si{mL/kg/min})} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
& {\makebox[5em]{Male}} & {\makebox[5em]{Female}} \\
\midrule
20--29    & 46.1 & 38.2 \\
30--39    & 38.5 & 43   \\
40--49    & 26.7 & 21.6 \\
50--59    & 29.1 & 30.6 \\
$\geq 60$ & 28.3 & 27.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}

\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
\DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
\captionsetup[table]{position=top}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setcounter{table}{1}% just for the example, isn't it?

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Cardiorespiratory fitness stratified by age}

\begin{tabular}{
    @{}
    c                   % Column 1
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 2
    S[table-format=2.1] % Column 3
    @{}
}

\toprule
Age & \multicolumn{2}{c}{VO2 (\si{mL/kg/min})\tnote{b}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
& {\makebox[5em]{Male}} & {\makebox[5em]{Female}} \\
\midrule
20--29    & 46.1 & 38.2 \\
30--39    & 38.5 & 43   \\
40--49    & 26.7 & 21.6 \\
50--59    & 29.1 & 30.6 \\
$\geq 60$ & 28.3 & 27.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[b] VO2 means…
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree. Thank you

Comment: I would like the caption "Cardiorespiratory fitness stratified by age" centered over the last table. Furthermore, I need table notes at the bottom of the table, explaining what VO2-max is. This is what I have imagined:  a^VO2-max=Cardiorespiratory fitness. Could someone please help me with this. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Svein Use `threeparttable`. I added the example.

Comment: Thank you very much for valuable help :)!